# Poweredge 1950 iii SO LOUD with 8gb fb-dimm stick

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, cooling

I understand that the 1950 family is pretty notorious for the fan speed sound like a jet engine taking off.

I just flashed the bios to the latest version, and now it can support my 8x8gb FB-DIMMS! Yay right? Well, after installing the ram, and of course rebooting so the configuration change 'sticks', the fans are still so loud! Since I have two 1950s I am able to side-by-side compare them and I noticed that when I have 4x4gb sticks in one, and only 1x8gb in the other, the 1x8gb server is way louder than the other one!

It seems that it is being set off specifically by the presence of 8gb in one slot as opposed to a total amount of ram. When I felt the dimms they were not any hotter, in fact the 4x4 gb sticks might have even ran hotter.

I looked all over the bios and do not see anything I can do. No real support available from my research, all the posts I could find would involve me manually replacing all the fans with new fans (which I might have to do anyway, even the 4x4gb fan noise was a bit high for my comfort)

I'm guessing I am just SOL on this one, right guys? Really hope someone has a suggestion

Thank you!

EDIT: I did not see any similar questions where the issue was specifically related to noise being increased by a single 8 gb DIMM, so I still think this question should be open.

Comment: Don't put this server in your bedroom.

Comment: Unfortunately, yeah, this server series is just loud.  Kind of like a cross between a hair dryer and a 747, am I right?

Comment: Dell support probably is silent on the subject, yes?

Comment: I hope this question stays open, I'd like to hear if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: @Ward Sorry to disappoint you...

Comment: @HBruijn Now that you're a mod, I guess closing is your forte.

Comment: (I was hoping more people would comment along the lines of "silent...," "hear...," "forte...")